# Odata $filter not retrieving the values

Tags: javascript, filter, odata, jaydata

I have a JS which has odata `$select` and `$filter` to retrieve a field called `"ct_portfolioid"` filtering using the `ct_portfoliocode`

The url does not seem to return the portfolioid.The url is undefined.

```
var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
        var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
        var filter="ct_apxportfoliocodeSet?$select=ct_portfolioid&$filter=ct_portfoliocode eq '" + portfolioCode +"'";

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/"+filter,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you get as a response? Ideally grab a trace of the request/response with some tracing tool (for example fiddler).

Comment: @VitekKarasMSFT thanks for your inputs.I found the error I replaced           var filter="ct_apxportfoliocodeSet?$select=ct_portfolioid&$filter=ct_portfoliocode eq %27" + portfolioCode +"%27";    url now returns the portfolioid-Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to handcoding protocol data you can give a try to [JayData](http://jaydata.org) that gives you a high level, semantic API over OData with JavaScript Language Query and native crud operations support.

With JayData you don't have to manually assemble oData `$filter, $sort, $select`, etc expressions, plus you can use native JavaScript syntax.

The query above can be implemented much easier with JayData:

```
$data.YourContext.filter(function(a) {return a.ct_portfolicode==this.portfolioCode;}, {portfolioCode: YourValue})
.map(function(p) {return p.ct_portfolioid;})
.toArray(...);
```

You can download the latest JayData version from [CodePlex](http://jaydata.codeplex.com)